# Slick2D - Cannot instantiate the type Image

Tags: image, slick

I am getting this strange error and I cannot for the life of me figure out why:

```
    Cannot instantiate the type Image
```

#### CODE:

```
import java.awt.Image;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class MainMenuState extends BasicGameState {

    int stateID = -1;

    Image background = null;
    Image startGameOption = null;
    Image exitOption = null;

    float startGameScale = 1;
    float exitScale = 1;
    MainMenuState( int stateID ) 
    {
       this.stateID = stateID;
    }


    public int getID() {
        return stateID;
    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        try {

        background = new Image("data/menu.jpg");

        Image menuOptions = new Image("data/menuoptions.png");

        startGameOption = menuOptions.getSubImage(0, 0, 377, 71);

        exitOption = menuOptions.getSubImage(0, 71, 377, 71);

        }catch (SlickException e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

    }

}
```

Why do I get this error? I've googled endlessly and nobody else has it, this worked fine in my other game. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing this right at the top of your code:

```java
import java.awt.Image;
```

So you're actually trying to instantiate the [Java AWT Image class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html), which is abstract, so no wonder you're getting that error. I'm guessing you used your IDE's suggestion to import a namespace.

Slick2D's Image class is located in the `org.newdawn.slick` namespace, which you never import. The Slick2D Image class simply doesn't exist as far as your code is concerned - but the java.awt Image class does.

`import org.newdawn.slick;` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Why? I've made two programs so far that have all used Image background = null; and then background = New Image(filepath); in the init() method. But in this program it doesn't? I haven't changed anything.

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Slick2D. But that's why you're getting your error - you're instantiating it and you can't. This was a very literal answer. Maybe you're using a different Image type to what you think, or you're constructing an Image elsewhere via, say, the `Image()` or `Image(Image)` constructors which are protected. It would help if you knew exactly which line was throwing this error.

Comment: Line 32: background = new Image("data/menu.png");. Cannot instantiate the type Image. I have a separate eclipse open and I typed out the exact same code (declared, then initialised in init() ) and it works perfectly. Try it in my Eclipse 2 and I get this error. I am lost.

Comment: @speakon I noticed something and edited my answer.

Comment: @speakon You're welcome. :)